# Invaild Json Result through Web Api in angular js

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, string, asp.net-web-api

I have build a http post web api in asp which return the following string in Json

```
RootObject rootObject = new RootObject()
{
     status = "User Registered"
};

     msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject);
```

Below is my angular js controller in which I am consuming that web api

```
.controller('signupCtrl', function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$state,$ionicHistory) {

$scope.signup=function(data){

  var link = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/Home/RegisterUser';

  //using http post
  //passing values to parameter
  $http.post(link, {RegisterName : data.name, RegisterUserName : data.username, RegisterPassword : data.password , RegisterEmail: data.mail , RegisterMobile : data.mobile})
    .then(function (res){    //if a response is recieved from the server.

      $scope.response = res; //contains Register Result

      console.log($scope.response);
    });
   }
 })
```

With the above code I am getting following result in google chrome console

[image: With the above code I am getting following result in google chrome console]

I am try to get that status only to match it value but I am unable to do so.
The doubt I am having is that json format

Comment: you want only `status` .. am i right ??

Comment: You can access status value by accessing the data object from the result easily. What is the problem here ?

Comment: So what's the problem? You can access `data` string in your **Object** and then parse it as Json.

Comment: Yes  @KishanOza you are right

Comment: $scope.response = res.data; gives me this "{"status": "User Register"}" But when I am trying to get $scope.response.status in console.log it return undefined.

Comment: have u try `console.log($scope.response.status)`  ?? @Kakashi_Hatake

Comment: yes @KishanOza is return undefined in console

Comment: alert `JSON.stringify($scope.response)` this will also helps you to understand the `JSON` response

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.response))` will do what you need.

If you're wanting those particular value, you can just access those and pass them to log.

```
console.log($scope.response.data['status']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you get the json as :

$scope.response = res.data;

might be you require  JSON.parse(res.data) or $.parseJSON(res.data) for getting json object